# Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found when trying to write data on S3 bucket from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to write data on an S3 bucket from my local computer:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('application') \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", configuration.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", configuration.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark.readStream \
    .format('kafka') \
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', kafka_server) \
    .option('subscribe', kafka_topic) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

streaming_query = lines.writeStream \
                    .format('parquet') \
                    .outputMode('append') \
                    .option('path', configuration.S3_PATH) \
                    .start()

streaming_query.awaitTermination()
```

Hadoop version: 3.2.1,
Spark version 3.2.1

I have added the dependency jars to pyspark jars:

spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.1,
aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.375,
hadoop-aws:3.2.1,

I get the following error when executing:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.start.
: java.io.IOException: From option fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found
```

Comment: That error occurs on which line in the above code sample?

Comment: I am getting the same issue

Comment: In my case, it worked in the end by adding the following statement:  .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider') \

Comment: Also, all the hadoop jars in site-package/pyspark/jars must be in the same version, hadoop-aws:3.2.2, hadoop-client-api-3.2.2, hadoop-client-runtime-3.2.2, hadoop-yam-server-web-proxy-3.2.2

Comment: For version 3.2.2 of hadoop-aws, aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.563 package is needed

Comment: Thanks all in advance. My spark version  upgraded from 3.1.2 to 3.2.3 , can someone please help what is the fix ?

Answer (score 14):

In my case, it worked in the end by adding the following statement:

```
.config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider')
```

Also, all the hadoop jars in site-package/pyspark/jars must be in the same version, hadoop-aws:3.2.2, hadoop-client-api-3.2.2, hadoop-client-runtime-3.2.2, hadoop-yam-server-web-proxy-3.2.2

For version 3.2.2 of hadoop-aws, aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.563 package is needed.

Also I replaced guava-14.0.jar with guava-23.0.jar.

Comment: So did you update hadoop version from 3.2.1 to 3.2.2 ?

Comment: How do you know exactly which jars you need for your version of spark?

Comment: Where did you add this line exactly? in your SparkSession.builder.master?

Answer (score 0):

I used same package with you.
in my case, when i added below the line.

```
config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider')
```

i got this error.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.parquet.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'

....
```

For solving this I installed `guava-30.0

Comment: Hi Doosik, yes I had to change guava jar too, in my case it was 23.0. I will update the above.

Answer (score 0):

try to download jar lib put into spark/jars
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.2/hadoop-aws-3.2.2.jar
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.563/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.563.jar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31912769)

Answer (score 0):

Following configuration worked for me

```
spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test") \
     .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.12.365") \
     .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider') \
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", '<your access key here>') \
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "<your secret key here>") \
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
     .getOrCreate()
```