# I cannot connect to S3 using PySpark from local machine (Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm reading streaming data from Kafka using PySpark but when I want to write the streaming data to S3 I receive an error message: `Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found`

This is part of my code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split, col, from_json, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType, TimestampType, MapType, ArrayType
from sparknlp.pretrained import PretrainedPipeline

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('twitter_app')\
    .master("local[*]")\
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.563,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.2,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-api:3.2.2,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-runtime:3.2.2,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy:3.2.2')\
    .config('spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown', 'true')\
    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId', ACCESS_KEY) \
    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey', SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) \   
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType() \
  .add("data", StructType() \
    .add("created_at", TimestampType())
    .add("id", StringType()) \
    .add("text", StringType())) \
  .add("matching_rules", ArrayType(StructType() \
                                   .add('id', StringType()) \
                                   .add('tag', StringType())))

df = spark.readStream \
          .format("kafka") \
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094") \
          .option("subscribe", "Zelensky,Putin,Biden,NATO,NoFlyZone") \
          .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
          .load() \
          .select((from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema)).alias('text'), 
                   col('topic'), col('key').cast('string'))


df.writeStream \
  .format("parquet") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "s3a://data-lake-twitter-app/checkpoint/") \
  .option("path", "s3a://data-lake-twitter-app/raw-datalake/") \
  .start()
```

And this is the full error message:

```
22/03/28 21:27:37 WARN MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
22/03/28 21:27:37 WARN FileSystem: Failed to initialize fileystem s3a://data-lake-twitter-app/raw-datalake: java.io.IOException: From option fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.writeStream \
      2   .format("parquet") \
      3   .option("checkpointLocation", "s3a://data-lake-twitter-app/checkpoint/") \
      4   .option("path", "s3a://data-lake-twitter-app/raw-datalake/") \
      5   .start()

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/spark_home_lab-iuwyZNhT/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/streaming.py:1202, in DataStreamWriter.start(self, path, format, outputMode, partitionBy, queryName, **options)
   1200     self.queryName(queryName)
   1201 if path is None:
-> 1202     return self._sq(self._jwrite.start())
   1203 else:
   1204     return self._sq(self._jwrite.start(path))

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/spark_home_lab-iuwyZNhT/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/spark_home_lab-iuwyZNhT/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    109 def deco(*a, **kw):
    110     try:
--> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
    112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/spark_home_lab-iuwyZNhT/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.start.
: java.io.IOException: From option fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.loadAWSProviderClasses(S3AUtils.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.createAWSCredentialProviderSet(S3AUtils.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.<init>(FileStreamSink.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.createV1Sink(DataStreamWriter.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.startInternal(DataStreamWriter.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:248)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClasses(Configuration.java:2642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.loadAWSProviderClasses(S3AUtils.java:628)
    ... 25 more
```

After checking other questions in stackoverflow might be that I'm not using the correct versions of those jar packages, how can I check the ones I need to install? I'm also using a piping environment, I don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: Duplicate question check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546208/class-org-apache-hadoop-fs-s3a-auth-iaminstancecredentialsprovider-not-found-whe

Answer (score 0):

try to add

.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")

to avoid java.lang.ClassNotFoundException